# What is the geometric interpretation of the following set?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $C$ be a circle (with arbitrary radius). Also there are two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ which can move along this circle freely. Let us choose a parametrization of this circle just by choosing polar angle $\phi$ as parameter. Then position of each points $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be denoted by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ respectively. OK. Let ask the following question:
If we consider all possible positions of the above two points we get a set (which we shall call $T_{1,2}$) of pairs 
$$ T_{1,2} = \{(\phi_1, \phi_2)\,\lvert\,  \phi_1, \phi_2 \in [0,2\pi]\}.$$
What is the geometrical interpretation of $T_{1,2}$?
It is easy because $T_{1,2}$ can be considered as Cartesian product of two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$:
$$T_{1,2} = C_1 \times C_2,$$
which is **torus**. BUT. What it would be if the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ were **indistinguishable** in the previous example. What the geometrical interpretation of all possible positions of this points it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we consider all possible positions of the above two points we get a set (which we shall call $T_{1,2}$) of pairs 
>   $$ T_{1,2} = \{(\phi_1, \phi_2)\,\lvert\,  \phi_1, \phi_2 \in [0,2\pi]\}.$$
>   What is the geometrical interpretation of $T_{1,2}$?
>   It is easy because $T_{1,2}$ can be considered as Cartesian product of two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$:
>   $$T_{1,2} = C_1 \times C_2,$$
>   which is **torus**.

Strictly speaking, the torus $\Bbb T^2$  is a quotient space of the square $ T_{1,2} = \{(\phi_1, \phi_2)\,\lvert\,  \phi_1, \phi_2 \in [0,2\pi]\},$ where for each $x\in [0,2\pi]$ we glue together the boundary points $(0,x)$ and $(2\pi,x)$ and also the points $(x,0)$ and $(x,2\pi,x)$. So if the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ are indistinguishable, we also have to glue together points $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ for each $x,y\in [0,2\pi]$. When we glue them we obtain a triangle. When we next glue its boundary points, we should obtain the Möbius strip. Unfortunately, my geometric imagination is weak and I don’t see this, but there are some mentions about it. For instance, in [Wikipedia article about Möbius strip it is said to be the configuration space of two unordered points on a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Applications).